# View Engines for Web Matrix Web Pages

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, viewengine, asp.net-webpages

Microsoft has a new website editing tool: WebMatrix. WebMatrix uses the new Web Pages engine in which Razor is the view engine; Razor is also the new view engine for MVC3. I am attempting to find out if it is possible to register and use a different view engine in Web Pages (like you can in MVC).

Does anyone know if it is possible to add or replace the view engine in Web Pages? If so has anyone documented this? Examples?

Comment: What's the new Web Pages engine?  Can't you just use MVC and mix and match there?

Comment: The ASP.NET team has stated (and you've confirmed with Reflector) that asp.net web pages are not technically tied to Razor, just as MVC3 is not.  I have not, however, seen examples on how to register something like Spark with web pages .. and the team's blogs indicate they will visit this later.  So I'd encourage you that it can be done, but I unfortunately cannot offer advice on how to achieve.

Comment: added an answer with my current thought pattern.  I'll try to hook Spark later if I can find some time.  Interesting problem you've presented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm hoping to try this myself a bit later, but for now I'll just share my current thoughts*:

In WebPages, Razor works by registering a BuildProvider with the ASP.NET build pipe for .cshtml and .vbhtml.

WebPages, in turn, registers the .cshtml .vbhtml extensions to its handler.

When a webPages page is requested, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler passes the path to the build pipe, where the extensions are matched with the registered Razor Provider, which renders the page and passes back a WebPage object, which handler passes to IIS and is served up.

You'll see all this if you use a reflection tool.  Both of these are achieved in the PreApplicationStartCode.Start() of the corresponding assembly.

Razor hooking its build provider:

```
public static void Start()
{
    if (!_startWasCalled)
    {
        _startWasCalled = true;
        BuildProvider.RegisterBuildProvider(".cshtml", typeof(RazorBuildProvider));
        BuildProvider.RegisterBuildProvider(".vbhtml", typeof(RazorBuildProvider));
    }
}
```

WebPages hooking the WebPageHandler

```
public static void Start()
{
    if (!_startWasCalled)
    {
        _startWasCalled = true;
        WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("cshtml");
        WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("vbhtml");
        PageParser.EnableLongStringsAsResources = false;
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(WebPageHttpModule));
        ScopeStorage.CurrentProvider = new AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider();
    }
}
```

To override we'd need to create and register a separate BuildProvider with the ASP.NET pipe to render our pages.  System.Web.WebPages provides a WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension() method which in theory you can hook a different BuildProvider to which will get the WebPage request instead of Razor.

Several blogs mention the RegisterExtension method, but there is also an open connect bug report showing it doesn't work 100%.  It may be more appropriate to just override everything and hook our buildprovider to the pipe (not using the method).

Web.config provides a construct to register buildProviders, so I'll prob try that.

```
<buildProviders>
   <add extension=".cshtml" type="CustomStuff.CustomBuildProvider"/>
</buildProviders>
```

The challenge is that most of the view engines out there use ViewEngines.Register(), a concept that webPages does not appear to have.  So we'd have to wrap those view engines in a BuildProvider and/or create a BuildProvider that can successfully invoke IViewEngine

Again, just sharing my thinking.  I'll try to register Spark or something later if I find some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "register" view engines in Web Pages in the same way as MVC. You just mix and match file types. There's nothing to stop you adding .aspx files to your Web Pages site. Web Pages is much more akin to a Web Site project in VS.

Comment: I'm trying to add my own view engine, not an .aspx or other currently supported page type.

Comment: If you want to use your own view engine, you need to use a framework that supports that such as MVC, like mellamokb said. Web Pages doesn't support that kind of extensibility.

Comment: I currently use MVC but occasionaly I would like a simpler framework like WebMatrix + Web Pages. Using Reflector on Web Pages shows that registration is going on - which makes sense because Razor is a registerable engine. Web Pages may be locked to Razor, I don't know.